I have problems trying to start the android studio emulator
[When trying to start the android studio emulator it asks me to install android emulator hypervisor driver, and I tried to look for solutions but I couldn't find anything.

So far I have not been able to run the emulator, since at first it asked me to install HAXM but I couldn't because VT-x was disabled. When I managed to install it, this message appeared which I don't know how to solve

Access your computer BIOS and turn virtualization ON. Do you use an INTEL or AMD?

Also, take a lot at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration?view=net-maui-8.0

I am an Intel user
